# Law of Natural Growth World Problem: How many years will it take to sell 100 franchises?

Tags: calculus, integration, solution-verification

> Pizza Unlimited is a national pizza firm and is selling franchises throughout the country. The president estimates that the number of franchises N will increase at a rate of $15$% a year, that is, $$\frac{dN}{dt}=0.15N$$
>
> Assuming the number of franchises at $t=0$ is $40$, how many years will it take for there to be $100$ franchises?

My work for this problem is shown below. Seeing as my answer was over $600$ years, I have a strong feeling I did something wrong. However, I'm having a hard time determined where I made my error.

**What did I do incorrectly, if anything?**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the right hand column, directly under the pink thing, you have 
$$
100=(.15t+3ln(2)+ln(5))ln(e).
$$
You took the natural log of the right hand side, but not of the left hand side. That equality should be 
$$
ln(100)=(.15t+3ln(2)+ln(5))ln(e).
$$

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank-you very much!